# Compute the determinant $D_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I would like to compute: $$D_n=\begin{vmatrix}1&-2&&&&\\2&2&-2&&0&\\&6&3&-2&&\\&&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\\&0&&\ddots&\ddots&-2\\&&&&n(n-1)&n\end{vmatrix}$$

I don't see any recurrence... We can factor the $n$ in the last line, but after that, all what I get is messy.

Comment: One way of doing this is to add multiples of column $i$ to column $i+1$, starting with $i=1$, to kill off the $-2$ superdiagonal, which would leave a lower triangular matrix, whose determinant is the product of what's left on the diagonal.

Comment: Computing this for $1\le n\le 10$, OEIS indicates that this might be [A052585](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+6%2C+30%2C+264%2C+2520%2C+30960%2C+428400%2C+6894720%2C+123742080%2C+2478470400&language=english&go=Search).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting $n-1$-times the  nth column form the $n-1$st columns yields
$$
D_n = \det\pmatrix{* &*  &*  \\
* & 3(n-1) & -2\\
0 & 0 & n
}
$$
entries with $*$ are unchanged. 
Then
$$
D_n = n \det\pmatrix{* &*   \\
* & 3(n-1)} = n \det\pmatrix{* & * & 0 \\* & * & -2  \\
*&* & 3(n-1)} \\
= n \left( \det\pmatrix{* & * & 0 \\* & * & -2  \\
*&* & n-1} + \det\pmatrix{* & * & 0 \\* & * & 0 \\
*&* & 2(n-1)}\right),
$$
where in the last step I used that the determinant is linear with respect to the columns of the matrix. Now the first determinant in the equation is $D_{n-1}$, the second is $2(n-1)D_{n-1}$.
This implies
$$
D_n = n ( D_{n-1} + 2(n-1)D_{n-2})
$$
with $D_1=1$. Setting $D_0=1$ makes the formula also valid for $n=2$.

Comment: I don't see how to get the recurrence relation, I have: $D_n = n \begin{vmatrix} * & * &* \\*& n-2&-2\\ 0& (n-1)(n-2) & 3(n-1)\end{vmatrix}$... And now?